# ZF2 console route and ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework2, console, acl

I've the follow problem with my application.

I make use of ACL, all works fine. I need to setup a Console module for some scraping. I've created te module with controller and route but when I run the command in my console I get an permission error from ACL.

My module.config.php;

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Cron\Controller\City'  => 'Application\Controller\CityController',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(

                'cronroute' => array(
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'getcities',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\City',
                            'action' => 'get'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

My controller;

```
<?php

namespace Cron\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
class CityController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function getAction()
    {
        echo 'Get cities';
    }
}
```

And part of my module.acl.roles.php

```
<?php

return array(

    # Guest
    'guest' => array(

        # Homepage
        'home',

        # Console routes
        'cronroute/getcities', // tried this one
        'getcities', // and this one
    ),
```

Than the result in the console by the command;

```
php public_html/index.php getcities



Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Permissions\Acl\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Resource 'cronroute' not found' in /home/..../domains/..../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Permissions/Acl/Acl.php:292
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ACL resource `cronroute/getcities` is wrong because it (normally) would check for route `getcities` as child from `cronroute`.

So the solution is to get rid of `/getcities` behind cronroute in `module.acl.roles.php` and everything should be fine.